# Как найти совпадения в тексте re - регулярные выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Нужно найти имя  записи (Mackenzie Semenova):

```
<span class="ellipsis event-row-participant style_participant__H8-ku">Mackenzie Semenova</span>
```

Что было сделано?

```
\W\w{4,10}\s\w{4,12}\W
```

Находит несколько совпадений, пожалуйста помогите найти только текст, имя и фамилию?

Comment: `(?<=>)[^<]+(?=<)` - че нить такое, текст между тегами, или `(?:[A-Z][a-z]+ ?){2}` два слова с буквы в верхнем регистре

Comment: Подходит, напишите пожалуйста ответ, ниже. Отмечу его как решение вопроса. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сильно не заморачиваться, то можно так: замечаем, что искомое находиться между >...<, используем две группы захвата и достаем внутреннюю.
import re

```
text = '<span class="ellipsis event-row-participant 
         style_participant__H8-ku">Mackenzie 
         Semenova</span>)'
pattern = re.compile(r'(>(.*)<)')
name = pattern.findall(text)
print(name[0][1])
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `BeautifulSoup`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<span class="ellipsis event-row-participant style_participant__H8-ku">Mackenzie Semenova</span>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print( soup.text )
# => 'Mackenzie Semenova'
```